# C error finding largest prime factor

Tags: c, primes

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

bool isPrime(unsigned long long x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    for (unsigned long long i = 3; i < sqrt(x); x += 2) {
        if (x % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long largest, number = 13195;

    for (unsigned long long i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i) && number % i == 0) {
            largest = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Largest : %llu\n", largest);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is the Prime number function working?
If I remove the sqrt() in the for-loop, I get an endresult of 0, which is strange...

I'm getting an output of 7, but the largest prime factor should be 29
Why is this happening?

Comment: Minor: I think you want `i <= sqrt(x)`.

Comment: It is not going to work for 2 (prime).  It's unclear what you mean by removing the sqrt.  Certainly i*i < x should work instead.

Comment: @hardmath  Would you use `i*i <= x`?  (added =)

Comment: @chux: I would, certainly for debugging/avoiding any problems with type conversion.  The multiply might not be faster than a double precision square root, but you know what they say about premature optimization.

Comment: @hardmath "multiply may not be faster than a double precision square root"? Are you kiddin'? Integer arithmetic is orders of magnitude faster that floating-point. (And yes, it is completely irrelevant where we are dealing with only 13195 iterations.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have a typo:

```
x += 2
```

should be

```
i += 2
```

This makes your `isPrime(29)` return `false`.

---

By the way, **why bother?** A much simpler solution would be to just factorize the number:

```
unsigned long long number = 13195;
unsigned long long i, max = 2;
unsigned long long orig = number;

for (i = 2; i <= orig; i++) {
    while (number % i == 0) {
        number /= i;
        max = i;
    }
}

printf("largest: %llu\n", max);
```

Comment: BTW: The `number /= i` does not seem to do much here.  A `if (number % i == 0) max = i;` looks sufficient.  Maybe it is for a general factorization?

Comment: OTOH: Maybe `for (i = 2; i * i <= number; i++) ...` with the rest as posted.

Comment: @chux if you leave the division out, this will give the largest divisor, not the largest prime factor.

Comment: @H2CO3 you should also point out the OP's incorrect isPrime function. It returns true for all odd prime squares because of `<` check instead of `<=` check in the `for` loop.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, the first idea: dropping `number /= i` does not work.  But the second idea: `for (i = 2; i * i <= number; i++)` works and is much faster.

Comment: @chux much faster than what? (BTW, speed is **completely irrelevant** when we have only some 13 000 iterations.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Certainly for a small fixed value like `13195`, the speed is irrelevant, but for a generic calculation of `long long number` finding OP's "finding largest prime factor", using `i * i <= number` is faster than `i * i <= orig`.  It is not faster when `number` itself is a prime, but far few iterations are needed when `number` is composite.  The `number /= i;` prides that nice reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Code error, change

```
// for (unsigned long long i = 3; i < sqrt(x); x += 2) {
for (unsigned long long i = 3; i < sqrt(x); i += 2) {
//                                          ^
```

---

For fun, `isPrime()` simplification:  (works for long long)

```
bool isPrime(long long x) {
  if (x % 2 == 0)
    return x == 2;
  long long i = 1;
  lldiv_t qr;
  do {
    i += 2;
    qr = lldiv(x, i);
    if (qr.rem == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  } while (i < qr.quot);
  return true;
}
```